# i got this error in my SteamBuilder out if nowhere how can i solve it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i got this error in my SteamBuilder out if nowhere  how can i solve it ?that is the error

> Exception caught by widgets library
> type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'String'
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>

here is my code

```
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: messages.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        String? data;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          print('=== data ===: ${snapshot.data}');
          List<Messages> listOfMessages = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
            listOfMessages.add(Messages.fromJson(snapshot.data!.docs[i]));
          }
```

```
child: ListView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    controller: scollcontroller,
                    itemCount: listOfMessages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return listOfMessages[index].id == email
                          ? ChatBubble(message: listOfMessages[index])
                          : ChatBubbleV2(message: listOfMessages[index]);
```

```
onSubmitted: (data) {
                      print('=== data ===: ${snapshot.data}');
                      messages.add({
                        'message': data,
                        'createdAt': DateTime.now(),
                        'id': email
                      });
                      controller.clear();
                      scollcontroller.animateTo(0,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                          curve: Curves.easeIn);
                      ;
                    },
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're taking a string value from the document snapshot and are casting it to a `Timestamp` - which is not a valid operation. It is impossible to say where in the code that is based on the information you provided though. Start from the stack trace that should be showing with your error message, and see where the error comes from. Then put a breakpoint on that line, run int he debugger, and check what actual value you are getting from the document/database.

Comment: problem is the code was working perfectly then all of a sudden this error showed up

Comment: Another problem, maybe not the one you're trying to solve, is that you're creating the stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder.  Don't do that.  Lift the state.  See my video for why: https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg